# Matlab ode15s: postive dx/dt, decreasing x(t)

Tags: matlab, ode

In my script, I call the ODE solver ode15s which solves a system of 9 ODE's. A simplified structure of the code:

```
[t, x] = ode15s(@odefun,tini:tend,options)
...


function dx = odefun(t,x)
  r1=... %rate equation 1, dependent on x(1) and x(3) for example
  r2=... %rate equation 2
  ...
  dx(1) = r1+r2-...
  dx(2) = ...
  ...
  dx(9) = ...
end
```

When reviewing the results I was curious why the profile of one state variable was increasing at a certain range. In order to investigate this, I used conditional debugging within the ode function so I could check all the rates and all the dx(i)/dt equations.

To my big surprise, I found out that the differential equation of the decreasing state variable was positive. So, I simulated multiple rounds with the F5-debug function, and noticed that indeed the state variable consistently decreased, while the dx(i)/dt would always remain positive.

Can anyone explain me how this is possible?

Comment: How exactly do you propose we do that without the equations? Sadly we have not yet reached omniscience.

Comment: `ode15s` doesn't just blindly step through the integration. It also makes semi-random steps in order to compute higher-order derivatives. If you just pause while it is running, you will often see unusual states.

Comment: @excaza I would think that the exact equations are not very relevant to problem and only might distract. How would the exact equations help with this question?

Comment: You don't think others being able to reproduce your issue would help the question? Seriously?

Comment: Compute the entire solution and then call your ODE function with slices of the solution at some time. That is the real derivative. Don't pause it while it is running because not every call to `odefun` is a solution to the ODE.

Comment: @drhagen While being in the debugger mode, I have a breakpoint within `odefun` so every time `ode15s` returns to the system of ode's, I notice and can check the dx value. Sometimes I see that `t` didn't change, are these the semi-random steps you are talking about?

Comment: What are the values of the derivative after the solution?  Either using `deval` or evaluating `odefun` directly.

Comment: @Buijs Yes, don't monitor the integration that way unless you really know what you are doing.

Comment: @drhagen thanks for your help, by calling `odefun` with a slice of the solution it indeed shows a negative derivative. Still I find it weird that at almost every 'step' inside `odefun` the derivative shows to be positive though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not advisable to pause the integration in the middle like that and examine the states and derivatives. `ode15s` does not simply step through the solution like a naive ODE solver. It makes a bunch of calls to the ODE function with semi-random states in order to compute higher-order derivatives. These states are not solutions to system but are used internally by `ode15s` to get a more accurate solution later.

If you want to get the derivative of your system at particular times, first compute the entire solution and then call your ODE function with slices of that solution at the times you are interested in.